How to Pull a single Directory from a Git repo
The place I work for has a super large GitLab repo that I don't need to pull. I only need a specific directory to be able to work in, and push commits to the repo.
I have tried following guide on how to do this, and below are the commands I run
mkdir <dir>; cd <dir>; 
git init
git remote add origin <GIT_URL>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo <dir1>/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin <pull_branch_name>

However it still tries to pull the entire repo, instead of just the single directory I need. I check the .git/info/sparse-checkout file and it contains the dir1 that I need.
Ways to fix this or alternatives would be greatly appreciated!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+single+directory Please note --depth 1  --filter=blob:none  --no-checkout and git sparse-checkout

The sparsecheckout feature only control what files/directories get populated in your working directory. It does not have any impact on what information needs to be pulled from the remote repository.
If you want to minimize the mount of data pulled from the remote, you'll need to take advantage of git's partial clone and shallow clone features.
NB: This requires that the remote server supports partial clones! The following will work with github and gitlab, but may not work on self-hosted or corporate servers, depending on what software is being used for git hosting.
A partial clone allows you to pull only some data from the remote repository; other data will only be retrieved when necessary. Using the linux kernel as an example, this would allow us to do something like this:
git clone --no-checkout --filter tree:0 https://github.com/torvals/linux
cd linux
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo net/ax25/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout

This would initially download all commits, but would not download either trees or blobs. When we run the final git checkout, git will fetch the trees and blobs necessary to populate the sparse checkout directories.
Compare the size of this directory:
$ du -sh linux
714M    linux

With the size of a regular clone of the linux source:
$ du -sh linux-full
6.9G  linux-full

A shallow clone lets you truncate the commit history; this is mostly useful if you're creating a "disposable" clone (e.g., for running tests in CI or something):
$ git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/torvalds/linux linux-short
$ du -sh linux-short
1.9G    linux-short

That has a complete working tree checked out, but it only contains data from the most recent commit. You could combine this with filters and sparse checkouts, of course:
$ git clone --depth=1 --filter tree:0 --no-checkout https://github.com/torvalds/linux linux-short
$ git -C linux-short config core.sparsecheckout true
$ echo net/ax25/ >> linux-short/.git/info/sparse-checkout
$ git -C linux-short checkout
$ du -sh linux-short
13M     linux-short

See this article and the git-clone man page for more information.

Thanks everyone for the help I managed to find the answer
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout <REPO_URL>
cd "clone_dir"
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout set "/Git_directory"
git checkout <branch>

This clones the Metadata, but not the actual files, then uses sparse-checkout to set what directory I need, then checkout to get the directory.
Thanks again!
